# TP-Link WR740N router won't reset nor provide wireless access

Tags: router, wireless-router

Last week I needed to restart my router for an unknown reason. When it rebooted there were only two LEDs on (Power, and Internet connection).

I just tried to factory reset the router since wireless was no longer working, but the router wouldn't reset, even after pressing the button for more than 30 seconds.

For some reason I am also unable to access the router interface.

What are things I could try to do in order to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

unplug it from power, wait a while then plug again.